# Make two Joomla modules appear as one with a single outlined border?

Tags: css, joomla, joomla-extensions

I have two Joomla module positions. They are stacked in the same module position. I need for these two modules to appear on the web page as a single displayed module with a single border surround all of  it.

How can this best be accomplished without modifying PHP code for either of these modules? I'm thinking this might be done with CSS, but I'm not an expert with CSS. Maybe a Module Class Suffix added for both of these modules could make them appear appear seamlessly joined? If so, how do I do this?

Comment: You have two modules in the same position? I would put a div around the position, give it a class, and then use css to control how the position looks. Or you could use module chrome that does a check to see if the give module is first, last or in the middle of the position and applies classes based on that.

Comment: I probably know how to solve this with just CSS, without modifying your PHP, but I'd need to see the HTML that's being output. Can you paste in or link to it?

Comment: @Elin When you said put a div around the position, are you talking about modifying the Joomla template to do this?

Comment: @DavidGoss Sorry, this is on a intranet and not accessible.

Comment: there might already be a div for it. If so, simply add a border radius to it.

Comment: @Lodder How would the border cover both modules?

Comment: Yes I mean in the template index.php (at least if it is a standard Joomla template) and @Lodder is correct that usually the template will have this already, you just need to get the class name probably.

Comment: It's a commercial template and modifying it isn't an option since we need to get support for future updates. Could two Module Class Suffixes be created for top and bottom, where the bottom has it's border without the top, and the top Module Class Suffix has a border on the top without it on the bottom? To make it appear as one?

Comment: a lot of commercial templates have a *custom.css* file. This file is specifically to make changes to the template without editing all the c ore css files. The template will most likely already have a div wrapped around the 2 modules so add your code to the *custom.css* file. When you update you template, you will simply need to re-upload your *custom.css* file

Answer (score 0):

OKay, without being able to see the HTML, I'll pretend the two components get outputted as `<div>`s with the class `themodule`, and that some padding, borders and margins have been applied something like this:

```
.themodule {
    padding: 1em;
    border: 0.1em solid black;
    border-right: 0;
    margin: 2em;
}
```

If you add this:

```
.themodule + .themodule {
    padding-left: 0;
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0.1em solid black;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

That means any `.themodule` directy after another one will get the left padding, border and margin chopped so it butts right up against the previous one and visually is part of the same box.

Hopefully you can apply to your case, but let me know if you have questions.